# How to mock/stub vue-i18n?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n, vitest

I have started to replace Jest with [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) for my unit test library in my Vue 3 App.

I am trying to write unit test for a component that uses the [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) library to translate text within it but when I try to mount this component in my test file, it fails with the error:

> ReferenceError: t is not defined

What is the proper way to stub/mock `t` from `import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'` when writing tests using the vitest library?

Note since upgrading from Vue2 to Vue3 this does not work:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  global: {
    mocks: {
      $t: () => {}
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a list of some notable package versions:

```
"vue": "^3.2.31",
"vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.14",
"vite": "^2.9.0",
"vitest": "^0.10.2"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you want to mock this globally, no need to put same code in every test suite.

```js
// vitest.config.ts
import { mergeConfig } from 'vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import viteConfig from './vite.config';

export default defineConfig(
    mergeConfig(viteConfig, { // extending app vite config
        test: {
            setupFiles: ['tests/unit.setup.ts'],
            environment: 'jsdom',
        }
    })
);
```

```js
// tests/unit.setup.ts
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils"

config.global.mocks = {
  $t: tKey => tKey; // just return translation key
};
```

Comment: Still getting `TypeError: $setup.t is not a function`

Comment: @leonheess please provide more context, as I have no clue where $setup comes from, but you may notice that we are mocking `$t` not `t` here, maybe that's the cause of your issue. Try to replace it on either side.

Comment: In my setup script I do `import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'; const { t } = useI18n();`.

Comment: As far as I understand, in the question, they want to mock globally injected 't' in templates. You seems to want mock the libary aka useI18n module itself, you can do it with vi.mock() method, same as it was jest.mock() in jest. https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#modules

Comment: @Luckylooke I have the same problem. `$setup` comes from the composition api

Comment: Ok, probably composition API but not setup script, I assume.. because I have never face similar error so far. And if your global mock match the case you are using `t` or `$t` then I have no clue why it does not work for you, sorry ‍♂️

Comment: @leonheess you need to properly configure vuei18n for the composition api. Check my answer above in case you still need it.

Answer (score 6):

Panos Vakalopoulos’s answer worked for me.

And the code could be run globally.

See https://test-utils.vuejs.org/migration/#no-more-createlocalvue

```js
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig(
    // add config for test
    test: {
        environment: 'jsdom',
        setupFiles: 'vitest.setup.ts',
    }
);

// vitest.setup.ts'
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
const i18n = createI18n()
config.global.plugins = [i18n]
```

```js
// YourComponent.vue
<div id="app">
    <p>{{ t("message.hello") }}</p>
</div>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
    const { t } = useI18n()
</script>
```

```js
// component_test.ts
describe('xxx', () => {
    it('yyy', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(YourComponent);
    }
})
```

Note that if you use global config as `$t`, Luckylooke's answer would work.

```html
// YourComponent.vue
<div id="app">
    <p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
</div>
```

```js
// tests/unit.setup.ts
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils"

config.global.mocks = {
    $t: tKey => tKey; // just return translation key
};
```

Comment: what about when using composition api on your app? I followed your steps but I am getting `TypeError: $setup.t is not a function` error back.

Comment: @noel293 you need to properly configure vuei18n, check my answer above in case you still need it.

Answer (score 5):

I read [this tutorial](https://runthatline.com/vitest-mock-vue-router/) that teaches to mock *vue-router*, then I made a similar solution for *vue-i18n* and it worked.

`Component (HelloWorld.vue)`

```js
<script setup>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const { t } = useI18n();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="greetings">
    <h1>{{ t("commonsmessagehello") }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ t("localhello") }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ $t("message.success") }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<i18n src="../commons/locales.json"></i18n>
<i18n>
{
  "enUS": {
    "localhello": "local helloooooo"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

`Test`

```js
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from "vitest";
import { mount, config } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import HelloWorld from "../HelloWorld.vue";

vi.mock("vue-i18n");

useI18n.mockReturnValue({
  t: (tKey) => tKey,
});

config.global.mocks = {
  $t: (tKey) => tKey,
};

describe("HelloWorld", () => {
  it("renders properly", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, { });
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain("message.success");
  });
});
```

How you can see, it worked for `t` and `$t`.

That's not the ideal way. Someday I'll try to figure out how to do it globally for every test.

Comment: @diego thanks for the solution! what if I want to test the text inside "message.success"? I mean `expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Successfull');`

Comment: @BhagyaSwamy theoretically you need to load vue-i18n similarly to what you do in your app. However, I would say _"nobody"_ wants it, because you would be testing vue-i18n, instead of testing your logic/component.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. The global solution worked for $t() but not for t(). What's worse is that the error message was complaining about another import missing, it didn't mention i18n. If you have tried the global solution first via setupFiles, you have to remove it. It won't work together.

Comment: @Suzana Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063191/7910454

Answer (score 4):

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

describe('xxx', () => {
   it('yyy', () => {
      const i18n = createI18n({
         messages: {
            gb: {},
            nl: {},
            ...
         }
      });
      
      const wrapper = mount(YourComponent, {
         global: {
            plugins: [i18n]
         }
      });
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the composition API and getting `$setup.t` is not a function, this is because you are probably wrongly configuring the `createI18n` instance in your test setup:

```
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  allowComposition: true
})
config.global.plugins = [i18n]
```

Note that you need to add `legacy: false` and `allowComposition: true` in order to use the composition api, otherwise `$setup.t` is not going to be defined and you will get the `$setup.t` is not a function error.

Answer (score 1):

Global solution for composition API:

```
import { vi } from 'vitest';

vi.mock('vue-i18n', () => ({
  useI18n: () => ({
    t: (key: string) => key,
    d: (key: string) => key,
  }),
}));
```