# Mock formatting functions of vue-i18n with composition api globaly

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-i18n

**Solution:**

Add this to your jest init file. It only partially mocks the module. If you need to use `jest.resetAllMocks()` this may lead to an error, because you'll also reset this mock. Workaround could be to use it per test file, instead of using it globally.

```
// jest.init.js
import { createI18n, useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

jest.mock("vue-i18n", () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual("vue-i18n");
    useI18n: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      t: (key) => key,
    }),
  };
});
```

---

I'm using jest, vue-test-utils and vue3 (composition api). I want to globally mock the vue-i18n functions like `t('key')`. With options-api i just need to write

```
// jest.init.js
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils";
config.global.mocks = {
  $t: (text) => text
}
```

**How to achieve the same behaviour with composition api** and `const { t } = useI18n();`?

I tried the following:

```
// jest.init.js
import { createI18n, useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

jest.mock("vue-i18n", () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual("vue-i18n");
    useI18n: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      t: (key) => key,
    }),
  };
});
```

However, I'm still getting this console warning after running my test run:

```
console.warn [Vue warn]: Property "t" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

I've also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72432259/4065938) but it doenst help me to fix the console warning

---

**Edit**:
Here is my config and a code-snippet:

```
const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false, 
  messages, // set locale messages
  // other options
});

export { i18n };
```

```js
<template>
  <p>{{ t("foo.bar.route.description")    }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export default {
  name: "Foo",
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n();

    return {
      t,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please, provide the code that this warning refers to. It says about instance property. It's not directly tied to vue-i18n mock. What does "still getting" mean? Was there a warning before a mock?

Comment: I've provided my config and an example component. My test does simply mount the component `mount(Foo);`

"Still getting" means, that in my opinion the code is fine (productive code works as expected, no warnings), however the test does still print this warning.

Comment: I see no problem with this code. In this case it's only possible for this comp to cause this warning if setup function failed to execute and return { t }, e.g. useI18n is not a function. If that's the case there should be errors in console.

Comment: Okay I've figured out my problem. In some tests I've called `jest.resetAllMocks()` which resets the globally applied mock of vue-i18n. After changing it to `jest.clearAllMocks()` its working again!

Comment: Makes sense. Reset mocks is really a footgun.